# How can I print an array and a method from another class

Tags: java, arrays, histogram

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Histogram
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
  {
    Row[] numbers = {
           new Row("1  -  10"), new Row("11 -  20"), new Row("21 -  30")                 
           new Row("31 -  40"), new Row("41 -  50"), new Row("51 -  60")
           new Row("61 -  70"), new Row("71 -  80"), new Row("81 -  90"),
           new Row("91 - 100")
                };
for(Row number : numbers)
  System.out.print(number);   
Counter section = new Counter();
section.StarCounter();

}
```

it prints out something like this:

```
1  - 10|
11 - 20|
21 - 30|
*****************
*********
***
ect.
```

I would like it to print out something like:

```
1  - 10|*****************
11 - 20|*********
21 - 30|***
ect.
```

thanks in advance for any pointers, I'm probably just overlooking the obvious.

Counter class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Counter
{
  public void StarCounter() throws FileNotFoundException
  {
    File file = new File("alotofnumbers.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    int[] integers = new int[1000];
    int start = 0;
    int count1 = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    int count3 = 0;
    int count4 = 0;
    int count5 = 0;
    int count6 = 0;
    int count7 = 0;
    int count8 = 0;
    int count9 = 0;
    int count10 = 0;

    while (scan.hasNextInt())
    {
  integers[start++] = scan.nextInt();
}

for (int input : integers)
{
  if(input <= 10)
  {
    count1++;  
  }
  else if(input > 10 && input <= 20)
  {
    count2++;
  }
  else if(input > 20 && input <= 30)
  {
    count3++;
  }
  else if (input > 30 && input <= 40)
  {
    count4++;
  }
  else if (input > 40 && input <= 50)
  {
    count5++;
  }
  else if (input > 50 && input <= 60)
  {
    count6++;
  }
  else if (input > 60 && input <= 70)
  {
    count7++;
  }
  else if (input > 70 && input <= 80)
  {
    count8++;
  }
  else if (input > 80 && input <= 90)
  {
    count9++;
  }
  else if (input > 90 && input <= 100)
  {
    count10++;
  }
} 
  double counted1 = count1 / 2.7;
  double counted2 = count2 / 2.7;
  double counted3 = count3 / 2.7;
  double counted4 = count4 / 2.7;
  double counted5 = count5 / 2.7;
  double counted6 = count6 / 2.7;
  double counted7 = count7 / 2.7;
  double counted8 = count8 / 2.7;
  double counted9 = count9 / 2.7;
  double counted10 = count10 / 2.7;

  for(int star = 0; star <= counted1  ; star++)
  {
   System.out.print("*");

  }
  System.out.println();


  for(int star = 0; star <= counted2 ; star++)
  {
    System.out.print("*");
  }

   System.out.println();
   for(int star = 0; star <= counted3 ; star++)
   {
    System.out.print("*");
   }

     System.out.println();

   for(int star = 0; star <= counted4 ; star++)
   {
     System.out.print("*");
   }

    System.out.println(); 
    for(int star = 0; star <= counted5 ; star++)
    {
     System.out.print("*");
    }

      System.out.println();

    for(int star = 0; star <= counted6 ; star++)
    {
      System.out.print("*");
    }

     System.out.println();
     for(int star = 0; star <= counted7 ; star++)
     {
      System.out.print("*");
     }

       System.out.println();

     for(int star = 0; star <= counted8 ; star++)
     {
       System.out.print("*");
     }

      System.out.println();
      for(int star = 0; star <= counted9 ; star++)
      {
       System.out.print("*");
      }

        System.out.println();

      for(int star = 0; star <= counted10 ; star++)
      {
        System.out.print("*");
      }

       System.out.println();     


 }
 }
```

Apparently my post has to much code and I don't really have much more info to give so it wants me to type something random up.
     public class Row
     {
     private String rows;

```
public Row(String colums)
{
rows = colums ;
}

public String toString()
{
Counter section = new Counter();
return rows + "|" + "\n";
}

public void setRow(String colums)
{
rows = colums;
}

public String getRow()
{
return rows;
}

}
```

Comment: Something went wrong when posting I meant to say it prints

Comment: where is your `Counter`?

Comment: its the class the reads values from a .txt file and organizes the data into a star row as shown using for() loops , is it not possible to format it in my main(String[] args)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what your question is as the title doesn't seem to relate that closely to the question so I'm going to assume it's "is there are better approach for creating a histogram?".

You can't take the approach of printing all the titles (rows) and then printing the stars. They have to be done at the same time.

Because integer division in Java automatically rounds down, all of your counting code can be significantly reduced:

```
int[] counts = new int[GROUPS];
for (int i: inputs)
    counts[Math.min(GROUPS - 1, (i + 1) / 10)]++;
```

The `GROUPS` will need to be defined as a static class constant.

Then printing the counts can be simplified to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < GROUPS; i++) {
    System.out.print(String.format("%2d - %2d]", i * 10 + 1, i * 10 + 10));
    for (int s = 0; s < counts[i]; s++)
        System.out.print("*");
    System.out.println();
}
```

In fact this can be further simplified using Java 8 streams but that's probably more information than you are after at the moment.

Comment: Okay how can I print my rows and stars at the same time? Even if i have them in the same loop, it will not print them side by side, it will instead print my first array value, then all my rows of stars then print my second array value then all the stars again all of different lines.

Comment: @JadenHambley that sounds like a bug to me. Note that if you use `System.out.print` the next print will be on the same line. If you use `println` the next print will be on the next line.

Comment: What do you mean by bug? sorry for my ignorance new to programming.

Comment: if you have any idea on how i could print them out on the same lines it would be greatly appreciated, or how to avoid this bug, its an assignment that;s due tomorrow, thanks for the help!

Comment: @JadenHambley I'd need to see the code to find the bug. Can you add the code that prints the results to your question?

Comment: You mean my Row class? Ill add it in.

Comment: I added it in hope thiers something in there that can be done

Comment: No that's not what I meant. It's clear your Row class prints the heading line ok. I assume you have code in `main` that prints the heading and then the stars. I suspect you're just calling `section.Startcounter` inside your loop which is clearly incorrect. But you'll need to post the code.

Comment: The code i have in main is the top I have all my code posted @sprinter

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any opening or closing brackets for the for loop. section.StarCounter should be in the same loop.

Try this:

```
for(Row number : numbers){
System.out.print(number);   
Counter section = new Counter();
section.StarCounter();
System.out.println();
}
```

Notice the for loop has braces and the loop ends with a new line.

Comment: If I have them in the same loop it will print my first array value then all my rows of stars, then my second array value and then all my rows of stars again, still all on separate lines, all i would like to do is have my stars print beside my array values.

Comment: im still getting the same result, rows of stars appear underneath array objects. and instead of having all my loops print just once they print out once for each time an array object is printed.